# How to encode non-ASCII characters as \uXXXX sequences in express/jade

Tags: node.js, unicode, express, escaping, pug

I have the following express route:

```
var data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'aide-memoire'
    },
    {
        id:2,
        title: 'apres moi'
    }
];

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('photo/list', {
        data: data
    });
});
```

In my JADE template I'm getting that data like the following:

```
!!!5
html
    head
    body
        script
            var data = !{JSON.stringify(calculates)};
```

But I get that data array on a client like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = [
            { "id":1, "title": 'aide-memoire'},
            { "id":2, "title": 'apres moi'}
        ];
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I need to encode non-ASCII characters as \uXXXX sequences like the following:

```
[
    {"id":1, "title": "aide-m%E9moire"},
    {"id":2, "title": "apr%E8s%20moi"}  
]
```

How can I do that in express/jade?

Comment: Have you looked at this http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html?

Comment: How should I use that for my case?

Comment: It looks like the encoding you are looking for is unicode hex escape characters... I'm not sure how they work... try to google these keywords... good luck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
JSON.stringify(["ä", "ä"]).replace(/[\u0080-\uFFFF]/g, function(m) {
    return "\\u" + ("0000" + m.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4);
});
//["\u00e4","\u00e4"]
```

---

```
JSON.stringify([{title: "ä"}, {title: "ä"}]).replace(/[\u0080-\uFFFF]/g, function(m) {
    return "\\u" + ("0000" + m.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4);
});
//[{"title":"\u00e4"},{"title":"\u00e4"}]
```

---

Although this is completely useless and it eats CPU for nothing to provide larger responses :/ Remember that each CPU cycle used in node.js is a CPU cycle where the entire server is down unless you cluster.

Comment: What's about array of objects? [{title: "ä"}, {title: ""ä""}]

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference since the whole thing is being stringified

Comment: This is great for converting properties strings, like native2ascii does (without the JSON stringifying, of course). `propetiesString.replace(...)` --- thanks a lot.